# $scope variable is not updating in controller , in successful $http GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

**My code**

```
/* code written for my factory */

/**
*  service/factory
*
* Description
*/

angular
    .module('Translationapp')
    .factory('LogService', LogService);

LogService.$inject = ['$rootScope','$http', '$q', 'API_URL'];

function LogService ($rootScope,$http, $q,appurl) {

    var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: appurl+'getlogs',
    }

    var defer = $q.defer();

    var logdata =  {
        getLogs : getLogs,
        AllLogs : []
    }

    return logdata;

    function getLogs () {

        $http.get('http://localhost/welcome_translation/getlogs')
            .then(getLogsComplete)
            .catch(getLogsFailed);

        return defer.promise;      
    }

    function getLogsComplete (response) {

        logdata.AllLogs = response.data;
        console.log('responsedata ='+JSON.stringify(logdata.AllLogs)); // getting data here
        defer.resolve(response);

    }

    function getLogsFailed () {
        defer.reject('Some Error');
    }
}

/* code for my controller */

/*
controller for logs
*/

angular
    .module('Translationapp')
    .controller('LogsController', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$http', 'API_URL','$filter' , 'NgTableParams', 'LogService' , function($rootScope, $scope,$http, appurl,$filter, NgTableParams, LogService){

    $scope.currentindex = 1;

    $scope.logs = LogService.AllLogs;

    logs();

    function logs() {


        /**
        * Step 1
        * Ask the getLogs function for the
        * logs data and wait for the promise
        */

        return getLogs().then(function(response) {

            /**
            * Step 4
            * Perform an action on resolve of final promise
            */
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            $scope.logs = response.data; 
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.logs));   // here I am getting the data
            //return $scope.logs;
        });
    }

    console.log('All Log ='+ JSON.stringify($scope.logs)); // getting no data here

    function getLogs() {
      /**
       * Step 2
       * Ask the data service for the data and wait
       * for the promise
       */
      return LogService.getLogs()
        .then(function(data) {

            /**
            * Step 3
            * set the data and resolve the promise
            */
            return data;
        });
    }

    /* get list of roles */

    $http.get(appurl+'getroles')
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.roles = response;
            });

    $scope.onTimeSet = function (newDate, oldDate) {
        $scope.formattedDate = $filter('date')(newDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
    }

    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams(
            { 
                page: 1, 
                count: 5,

            },
            {
                total: $scope.logs.length,
                counts: [],
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                $scope.data = $scope.logs.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                $defer.resolve($scope.data);
            }
    });

}]);
```

Comment: you will never get data there becuase that call is getting executed even before the data has come.. you can check it by putting console.log statments

Comment: Where is the problem?  Is it the getLogs() update or the getRoles update that is not rendering?  Or both?

Answer (score 0):

I extracted the relevant part of your code:

```
getLogs().then(function(response) {
   $scope.logs = response.data; 
   console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.logs));   // here I am getting the data
});

console.log('All Log ='+ JSON.stringify($scope.logs)); // getting no data here
```

The problem is that the success handler passed to `then` is
called asynchronously when the logs are eventually 
retrieved. However, the `console.log` for which you see no output
happens right after the request for the logs has been issued but long before they are retrieved. That's the whole point about promises. You pass a handler to execute once the results are there. But you can immediately do other stuff regardless how long it takes until the promise is fulfilled.

If this is not clear to you I recommend to start with a JS
promise tutorial that teaches you the main concepts you need to
understand. This post might be helpful:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/